# Autoplay animate through image gallery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page which contains an image gallery inside a grid. I want the page to automatically select one image from the gallery and to run a css animation like enlarging the photo. The image must be selected at random and run automatically once the page has loaded with the gallery.

Just to give an idea: 
Visit: `<http://codepen.io/DouglasGlover/pen/zHBid/>`
In above link is an small gallery where images enlarge on hover. I don't want the hover to form the animation, instead I'd like the animation to happen without hovering. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hover class to your hover rules, and then on page load add the javascript code to select a random image and adds hover class to it.

```js
// Getting a random index for the list of images that are on the page.
var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.photo-image').length));

// Adding class hover to trigger the hover action.
$($('.photo-image')[index]).addClass('hover');
```

```css
.photo-image:hover,
.photo-image.hover
{
  width:200px;
  top:-50px;
  left:-50px;
  z-index:1001;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for this, greatly appreciated. Seems to work, how would I be able to return it to it's original state (before it was enlarged)?

Comment: you can remove the hover class from the element before enlarging

`$(this).removeClass("hover");`

in the click handler of the photo-image

Comment: I would appreciate it if you mark my post as a valid answer